# Joint SPX and VIX calibration - volatility surfaces construction

Tags: options, arbitrage, vix, volatility-surface, spx

I am currently researching the joint calibration problem of SPX options and VIX options. A question that comes to mind is the construction of each assets respective volatility surface.

In the articles I've looked there is no mention of constructing a volatility surface after having achieved a successful joint calibration.

To my knowledge, after having calibrated a model to market data it has to be checked/modified not to allow for calendar and butterfly arbitrage.

However, is this not also the case when building a volatility surface after a joint fit? Is this something that is obvious, so it is never mentioned? And lastly, even if you create arbitrage free volatility surfaces for each asset after the joint calibration, can we be certain that there is no arbitrage between the SPX and VIX?

Comment: For a joint calibration you are probably already given the smoothed and arbitrage free SPX vol surface, the VIX options surface, and the VIX futures term structure. You need to find a model that fits all three. At which stage of the process are you?

Comment: I might have misunderstood the process of calibration. As I understand it, we start with options prices of the SPX and VIX (in addition to VIX futures) and then calibrate a model to match the prices of all of the contracts simultaneously. Is this not the case?

Comment: Yes this is the case, but it might be easier to first smooth the SPX and VIX options surfaces in a way that both are arbitrage free and then calibrate the joint model to them. I suspect to calibrate the joint model you'll have to solve some sort of (forward) PDE which will require you to calculate partial derivatives. Having smoothed arb free SPX and VIX vol surfaces enables you to calculate these derivatives.